# Guess whether word is verb with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a code that identifies verbs in a .txt by common word endings. If a word isn't identified I want to guess with regex if a word could be a verb and let the user decide whether I'm right.

But I'm having difficulties with this part of the code. There is an error in the first line. I don't even get to the question. If I exchange `ur'(?u)[a-z]+ing'` with `'doing'` it works just fine.

```
        if word == ur'(?u)[a-z]+ing':
            print 'Is this a verb?', word
            usrinput = raw_input('Type yes for yes, no for no')
            if usrinput == 'yes':
                print 'yes'
            elif usrinput == 'no':
                print 'no'
                continue
```

Comment: You are just comparing string equality with the regular expression, not whether that regex `match`es (hint!) the `word`.

Comment: why would `==` all of a sudden start performing regex match?

Comment: you can just use `.endswith('.ing')` to do wht you want i think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `==` operator checks for *string equality*. It doesn't perform regex matching or any other kind of matching. In order to do this, you need a library, like the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library.

For example:

```
import re

word = raw_input('Please enter a word? ')

verb = re.compile('[a-z]+ing$')
if verb.match(word):
    print 'I think it is a verb'
else :
    print 'I think this is NOT a verb'
```

If you however are planning to do natural language processing, I think using part-of-speech tagging using the [*Natural Language toolkit (NLTK)*](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) will be more effective.

Comment: This will also match "bazinga" or similiar. I think you meant `[a-z]+ing$`

Comment: @NiklasB.: well that of course depends on how the OP will define verbs since not every word ending with "ing" is a verb, nor vice versa. But you are correct using the dollar at the end will *improve* the definition (modified).